# I'm trying to return a value using provider with a for-loop and fold

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

```
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int justdoit() {
    for (var i = 0; i < orderUp.length; i++) {
      tempList.add(orderUp[i].selectVar.amount);
    }

    int count =
        tempList.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
    return count;
  }

}
```

The provider is supposed to get all `amount`s from `orderUp` which are `int`s and are put in another list which uses fold to find the sum of all values in `tempList` and then return it.

```
List<int> tempList = [];
```

I'm trying to return on this widget

```
Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  context.watch<Counter>().justdoit().toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

But I don't get anything. I always get '0'

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Food food;
  DetailPage(this.food);

  @override
  State<DetailPage> createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<Counter>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 65,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
          child: Container(
            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined),
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
            child: Container(
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  ((context.read<FavFood>().favorited(widget.food) == false)
                      ? Icons.favorite_outline
                      : Icons.favorite),
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  bool click2 = context.read<FavFood>().favorited(widget.food);
                  (context.read<FavFood>().rev(widget.food));
                  (context.read<FavFood>().favorited(widget.food));
                  setState(() {
                    click2 = !click2;
                  });
                  context.read<FavFood>().favorited(widget.food);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff453658),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FoodImg(widget.food),
            FoodDetail(widget.food),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        height: 56,
        child: RawMaterialButton(
          fillColor: const Color(0xff453658),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          elevation: 2,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(cartRoute);
                  context.read<TotalPrice>().update();
                },
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  context.watch<Counter>().justdoit().toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `orderUp` can be empty ig

Comment: I made sure `orderUp` wasn't empty

Comment: can you update snippet with full sample widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: actually it is still not tracking the `orderUP`, if you are using github, can you share the link, or you can create a sample snippet with dummy data t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the code, it would be better not to use global variable. And as for the update you need to notifyListner to update the ui. For demonstration purpose,

You can create another variable

```dart
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int justdoitValue = 0;
  int justdoit() {
    print(orderUp.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < orderUp.length; i++) {
      bruhhh.add(orderUp[i].selectVar.amount);
    }

    int count =
        bruhhh.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
    justdoitValue = count;
    notifyListeners(); // depends on what do you want
    return count;
  }
```

And call on [food_quantity.dart#L137](https://github.com/shimomaru/2.0/blob/b0ae88d6249bfabf2d213ed66a8697e5bafb88ce/lib/screens/detail/widget/food_quantity.dart#L137)

```dart
 GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
   ..........
   context.read<Counter>().justdoit();
   }
```

And use [lib/screens/detail/detail.dart#L110](https://github.com/shimomaru/2.0/blob/b0ae88d6249bfabf2d213ed66a8697e5bafb88ce/lib/screens/detail/detail.dart#L110)

```dart
child: Text(
     context.watch<Counter>().justdoitValue.toString(),
```

And I think you may restructure the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You coule use those code, it would be better not to use global variable. And as for the update you need to notifyListner to update the ui. For demonstration purpose,